# How to submit an ASPX form using C# on the Pageload event

Tags: c#

I have form tag in an ASPX page,

```
<form id="payForm" method="post" action="<%Response.Write(URL);%>" runat="server">
</form>
```

On the pageload event,

```
Literal mylit = new Literal();
mylit.Text = string.Format("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"{0}\" value=\"{1}\" /> \n", name, value); 
payForm.Controls.Add(mylit);
```

**How do I make my form to submit after adding this control defined in pageload event?**

If I write this code

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        document.forms["payForm"].submit();
 </script>
```

then this snipet of code also cannot find the `payForm` object.

Comment: 1. why you need submitting the form? you could call methods directly from page load event.
2. have you try to document.forms["payForm"].submit() when document is loaded?

Comment: 1) i need to acually pass this form to paypal ... its shopping cart page. how to call method directly in page load event any snipet of code please  2) how can i know document is loaded and then try  document.forms["payForm"].submit()

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to submit the form through your server side application, only if it was using the GET method so you could just redirect to the formated url. Think you gonna have to use JS.

`document.forms["payForm"].submit()` doesn't work because document.forms is not an associative array. You have to use it like this: `document.forms[0].submit()` where 0 is the index of the form that you want to submit.

And you can also find your form inside the document element with the name attribute of it.

This way: `document.nameOfMyForm.submit()`

Comment: thnx for your response dear. but problem is when i use runat="server" attribute then document.forms[0].submit() or document.forms["payForm"].submit() does not work at all

Answer (score 0):

Hi albeit possible solution is nearly 4 years late nevertheless for future viewers:
I did something similar to what you want using javascript but by calling the function from my code back.
I did something like this :

pageload()
{

//set all control i needed here

// did other calculation etc

String s = @"< script >document.getElementById('formname').submit(); < /script >";

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", s, false);

}

And in my .aspx i did the following:

< form id="form1" action="pagetosubmit" method="post" runat="server" >

// my input tags / controls etc ...

< /form >